# Is there a way to make content scrollable even if it fits its parent?

Tags: css

I have a container which is quite large vertically and would like to make its content scrollable even though the content doesn't overflow its parent. Is this something that's not possible?

Example code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This div should be scrollable even though it fits the parent.
  </div>
</div>
```

Styling

```
.container {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Think about what the meaning of that would be... why would that make any sense? [Is this the real problem or are you trying to do something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: What would be the _point_ of that? Scrolling is essentially a mechanism to make content reachable that would not be reachable without it - _because_ it overflows the dimensions of its container. If you do not even have that case to begin with - then _why_ would you want to scroll? Are you trying to achieve a certain optical effect / functionality here? // You could of course f.e. add padding to your content, to _make it_ overflow the dimensions of the parent - https://jsfiddle.net/2jtsx0wf/ Whether that would be what you want here or not - impossible to tell, requirements to unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible to make its content scrollable even though the content doesn't overflow its parent. your just have to set the `min-height: 600px /*more then your container height*/` of your `.content`.

here is the code in snippet.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content {
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      This div should be scrollable even though it fits the parent.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank You...

Comment: You say it's possible to make the content scrollable even if it doesn't overflow its parent.... and your solution is to make it overflow its parent? Well, that's interesting.

Comment: sorry my mistake. i have to make change in it.